# Pointers and Reference C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am currently learning pointers and reference in class and it is a little bit confusing. We were assigned this problem for homework and I was wondering if someone can correct me?

[image: Problem]

From what I understood so far, * declares a pointer, and & declares a reference? So if you set a pointer variable equal to a reference, then the pointer variable stores the value of that address? And when you assign new, you allocate memory to a variable but I am not sure about afterwards. I read information from C++ but I am trying to make sure I actually know how to apply the information.

Thank You

Comment: `&` can mean either the address of or it is a reference - depending on context

Comment: Terrible assignment.

Comment: The answers to the homework is correct.

Comment: @EdHeal, on a second tought... Isn't &m(a) actually setting the address of m to the value of a? `&m = a;`

Comment: That is one way of implementing references  - but does not have to be the case.

Comment: It can either be at &m set the value of a, meaning the address for m is 52, or the value for m is the value of a.

Comment: @SimplyMe that was what I originally thought, but then I'm not sure how to show it on the assignment, so I assumed m was reference to a

Comment: @SimplyMe no, it is declaring a reference variable that refers to the same memory location as `a` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a(52)` declares an int with a value of 52.

`int b(22)` declares an int with a value of 22.

`int c(a)` declares an int with the value of `a`, so 52.

`int &m(a)` declares a reference to the int `a`. Since `a` has a value of 52, `m` has a value of 52. However, if you change the value of `a`, the value of `m` will change too. For example:

```
int a = 52;
int &m(a);   // Value of m is 52

a = 40;      // Value of m is 40
```

`int *x(&b)` declares a pointer `x` to the memory location of `b`. The behaviour is similar to the reference above. Since `b` has a value of 22, dereferencing `x` will give the value of `b`. If `b` is changed, then the value returned when dereferencing `x` will also change, but the address `x` points to will not. For example

```
int b = 22;
int *x(&b);

std::cout << x;  // Some hex number, say 0x7fff79205a6c, which is the address x points to
std::cout << *x; // will print 22, since b is 22

b = 40;

std::cout << x;  // Some hex number, 0x7fff79205a6c, which is still the address x points to
std::cout << *x; // will print 40, since b is 40
```

Update after comment question.

If you create a pointer by assigning another pointer to it, then that pointer will point to the same address as the pointer from which it was assigned. For example:

```
int b(22);
int *x(&b);  // Say this again points to 0x7fff79205a6c
int *y = b;
```

then

```
std::cout << x;  // 0x7fff79205a6c
std::cout << y;  // 0x7fff79205a6c
```

and

```
std::cout << *x; // prints 22
std::cout << *y; // prints 22
```

then modifying `b` will not change the address which `x` and `y` point to, but dereferencing `x` or `y` will return the new value of `b`.

Also, modifying the value pointed to by either `x` or `y` will have the following effects:

```
*x = 40; // b = 40 and *y = 40
```

Comment: For 
std::cout << x;  // 0x7fff79205a6c
std::cout << y;  // 0x7fff79205a6c 

shouldn't y be a different address? *y points to value of b, not the address of b?

Comment: No, it's the same address. A pointer points to some address, when you assign a pointer to another pointer, you are saying you want it to point to the same address. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec911f2eb05d1b30).

Answer (score 1):

`a(52)` gives a the integer value 52.

`b(22)` gives b the integer value 22.

`c(a)` gives c the integer value of a, meaning 52.

`&m(a)` at m's address, you have the value of a, so m has the same address with a.

`*x(&b)` at x, you assign the value of b's address.

I would say that your homework is correct.